# How do I get twilio 5 digit error code for a failed voice call?

Tags: twilio

We have a callback url in place that is correctly capturing the failed status of a call.

Our code then fetches from twilio the details of the call by doing the following:

```
$call = $twilio_client->calls($sid)->fetch();
```

Within the call details returned there is no 5 digit error code listed, even though the failed status is present.

How do we get the 5 digit error code that caused the failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Thanks to @miknik for the answer, however that is actually a deprecated resource (which is why you can't currently find any documentation on the matter). It's taken me a while to find the answer as I've been chasing down where the notifications have gone.

The Notifications API was deprecated in favour of the [Monitor Alerts API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/monitor/alerts). This API can give you all the details about an alert, including the 5 digit code.

The best way to receive these alerts for your application is to [set up a webhook in your account console](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/triggers/alert/create) which will send all the parameters about the alert as part of the request.

You can also [list your alerts](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/monitor/alerts#list) which will allow you to find alerts from a specific resource SID (in your case, a call SID).

Let me know if this helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Make an authenticated GET request to

/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountNumber}/Calls/{CallSid}/Notifications

So in PHP the following will retrieve the notification info for your call

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://{AccountNumber}:{AuthToken}@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountNumber}/Calls/{CallSid}/Notifications.json');
```

Then use this line to get the returned JSON into an associative array

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
```

Now if all you want is the error code its stored as the following variable

```
echo $obj[notifications][0][error_code];
```

However, the full error info is also returned as a URL encoded string. You can access this by first urldecoding it, and then parsing the query string into an array with the following line

```
parse_str(urldecode($obj[notifications][0][message_text]), $output);
```

And you can now access the variables within like this

```
echo $output[Msg]; // Error text for failure eg invalid phone number
echo $output[phonenumber]; // Phone number for failed call
echo $output[ErrorCode]; // 5 digit error code
echo $output[LogLevel];` // Log level of error eg WARN
```

As far as I know this is not implemented in the PHP helper library, so you have to code for it manually

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your answer.  My callback routine has already done a post to fetch the call sid and using that I fetch the call details using the code line in my question.  If would have thought that there is another method to append to the $twilio_client->calls($sid)->  WHAT GOES HERE that would provide the error code.  I am not overly familiar with GET but would need more clarification as to how your suggestion gets me what I want when I am already in my callback function.

Comment: Unfortunately @Tim I don't think this functionality is available in the Twilio helper library. I have edited my answer above to include step by step instructions.

Comment: Thank you so much @miknik for clarifying.  I will give this a try tomorrow and am certain it will work.  Any idea why twilio has a path of /2010-04-01/ in the request?  I am also making use of the version 5 library and submitted a ticket to them to see if there is some ver. 5 PHP helper library routine that can be called.  I find it interesting that they don't provide the error code directly as part of the call sid data.  I'll let you know what twilio's response is.  Thanks again.  You were most helpful, given my efforts to find the answer in Twilio's documentation proved futile.

Comment: /2010-04-01/ is simply the current API version.

Comment: Thanks for this answer miknik! This should actually be available in the PHP library though. The source can be found here: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/Call/NotificationList.php. To get the notifications for a call, you need to call `$call->getNotifications()`.

Comment: @philnash Tried this `$tw_call_details = $call->getNotifications();` and got this PHP Fatal error:  `Call to protected method`  Using v5 library.

Comment: Bah, sorry my fault, just call `$call->notifications`.

Comment: @philnash @miknik  I was able to successfully get the call details using `$call->notifications`.  I forced a call failure using Twilio's 500-555-0001 number.  I did see a 'failed' status in the call notification, however there was no 5 digit error code to be found.  I did find in the data passed to the callback url for a voice call, the SIP failure code, which for now solves my issue.  I have opened a ticket with Twilio (actually did that 3 days ago and still no answer).  So I will let you know what they say with regard to how to actually get a their 5 digit error code for a failed voice call.

Comment: @miknik  Have not tried your solution but since i have the sip error code I am moving on.

Comment: Glad you got what you need Tim. @philnash Thanks for the source link, I had a look but I'm not at the level to get my head round how all that code ties together just yet. I'm teaching myself php so I find questions on here to try and solve so I can learn as I go. You on the other hand are clearly some kind of Twilio deity, if I see a new Twilio post and you have answered I just keep on walking ;)

Comment: Tim, I've added an answer that I think may help too. @miknik I'm impressed seeing you around answering things too, I'm really happy to see that you're trying to use Stack Overflow as a way of learning. I just work for Twilio, so try to use that to help people on here too.